# Loading specific test file for debugging MSProject Add-In

Tags: vsto, visual-studio-debugging, ms-project, project-properties

I am developing a MSProject add-in with VSTO and I have a question about debugging.

How do I use the **Start Option->Command line arguments** to load a specific MS Project file?

I have tried using `[drive:][path]filename.mpp` but the file doesn't load.

Otherwise everything is fine. I can load a file manually and debug properly.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command line example to load **MS Project** with a specific MPP file:

> winproj "c:\projects\Annual Report Preparation.mpp"

For **Visual Studio Project->Debug->Start Options->Command Line arguments** - you can use the path enclosed in quotations. The gotcha here is that you must also assign the **Start Action->Start External program** for this to work - this is a VS bug.

> "c:\projects\Annual Report Preparation.mpp"

Use <kbd>...</kbd> and set **Start External Program** (*depending on your Office version*):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINPROJ.EXE

See [MS Office for further MS Project command line reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-project-HA010165551.aspx).